# Could not resolve host mongo, elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

We created a docker swarm for 2 containers, mongo (alias mongo), ES (alias elasticsearch). Because of the unique use case our application is not part of the swarm but it still on `bridge/default` network. We want to reach out to mongo & ES from our app but we face the error

```
gradle@f63662b54a29:~/project$ curl -XGET http://mongo:27017
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mongo
```

We are using the independent images available from mongo and ES.
These are the things we verified

1. `sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .HostConfig.NetworkMode }}'  container_id` All the 3 containers have the `default` network config
2. The containers belong to the same security group and all the traffic is open from itself
3. We experimented with bindIp values

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 // Also changed it to 0.0.0.0
```

4. We curled to `google.com` and it worked so shouldn't be a dns issue

Any pointers what else we could try to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Have you tried to telnet/curl `127.0.0.1` port `27107`. If it works you just need to add a entry for mongo in your hosts file.

Comment: If I try that from within the application container then 127.0.0.1 will point to itself. So I guess you mean trying from the server
```
astha@blah:config/docker-compose$ curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:27017
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Does this look promising? What is the hosts file ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the last part. Anyways, if you're trying to access mongo from inside another docker container on same network, you should try using the IP given to mongo by docker (something like 172.x.y.z).

Comment: Hosts file is the `/etc/hosts` file in linux which keeps mappings for custom names to IPs (local DNS)